# MongoDB : Find document where none of the subdocument matches criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, mongodb-.net-driver, subdocument

I want to find out document where `Record A` has `"FLD1"` and `"FLD1"` is not equal to `"VAL2"`, it means it should also return document where either `Record A` does not exist or either `FLD1` does not exist apart from `FLD1` is not equal to `VAL2`.

In following document, It should return Document `1, 3`, and `4`

- `1`: because `Record A` exists, FLD1 exists but Value of `FLD1` is not `VAL2`
- `3`: because `Record A` does not exists
- `4`: because `Record A` exists but `FLD1` does not exists

only 2 where `Record A` exists, `FLD1` exists and value of `FLD1` is equal to `VAL2`.

```
{
    _id:NumberLong("1"),
    Name:"Doc1",
    Records: [ 
        {
            "RecordName" : "Record A",
            "State" : 1,
            "Properties" : {
                "FLD1" : "VAL1"
            }
        },
        {
            "RecordName" : "Record B",
            "State" : 1,
            "Properties" : {
                "FLD2" : "VAL3",
                "FLD3" : "VAL2"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id:NumberLong("2"),
    Name:"Doc2",
    Records: [ 
        {
            "RecordName" : "Record A",
            "State" : 1,
            "Properties" : {
                "FLD1" : "VAL2"
                "FLD4" : "VAL1"
                "FLD5" : "VAL6"
            }
        },
        {
            "RecordName" : "Record C",
            "State" : 1,
            "Properties" : {
                "FLD1" : "VAL1",
                "FLD2" : "VAL3"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id:NumberLong("3"),
    Name:"Doc3",
    Records: [ 
        {
            "RecordName" : "Record B",
            "State" : 0,
            "Properties" : {
                "FLD2" : "VAL2"
                "FLD3" : "VAL4"
                "FLD4" : "VAL5"
            }
        },
        {
            "RecordName" : "Record C",
            "State" : 1,
            "Properties" : {
                "FLD3" : "VAL2",
                "FLD5" : "VAL4"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id:NumberLong("4"),
    Name:"Doc4",
    Records: [ 
        {
            "RecordName" : "Record A",
            "State" : 1,
            "Properties" : {
                "FLD2" : "VAL2"
            }
        },
        {
            "RecordName" : "Record C",
            "State" : 1,
            "Properties" : {
                "FLD3" : "VAL3",
                "FLD4" : "VAL4"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Does any one know how to write such query for mongo db?

Also, If I want to find out all the document where none of the sub document has Record Name with value `Record B`, How would I find out?

In that case, query should return document 2 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/index.html) operator embracing three separate filtering conditions:

```
db.collection.find({
    $or: [
        { "Records": { $not : { $elemMatch: { "RecordName": "Record A" } } } },
        { "Records.Properties.FLD1": { $exists: false } },
        { "Records": { $not : { $elemMatch: { "Properties.FLD1": "VAL2" } } } }
    ]
})
```

[$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) along with [$not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/index.html) allows you to check if all `Records` have `RecordName` not equal to `Record A`, then you can use [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/index.html) to check `FLD1` and another `$elemMatch` with `$not`:

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XRzfncZU09w)

Comment: Thanks @mickl, I had to modified it little, See provided answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mickl

I had to modify the answer little bit.

```
{
      $nor: [
        {
          $and: [
            {
              "Records": {
                $elemMatch: {
                  "RecordName": "Record A"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "Records.Properties.FLD1": {
                $exists: true
              }
            },
            {
              "Records": {
                $elemMatch: {
                  "Properties.FLD1": "VAL2"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```